# Searching an array for key words -python

Tags: python, arrays, split

```
array1=["hello","hi","hey"]
q1=input("say hello-""\n")

answer=q1.split()

if array1[:] in answer:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("fail")
```

I am trying to identify keywords from a user input this is what i have so far. I am planning to add a lot more code, but i can't quite get this part working. I think the problem is here:

```
  array1[:]
```

but i am not sure what to put inside the brackets to make the code check all the words in the array to compare to the user input's words.

I am fairly new to python, hope you can help.

Comment: Try `if set(array1).issubset(answer):`  It doesn't pay attention to order, though.

Comment: thanks for your help but it hasn't worked, i have just searched "issubset" and it might be helpful

Comment: is there a similar thing for "or" because not all elements from the array have to be in the user input

Comment: Try this: `if any(a in answer for a in array1):`

Comment: this works thank you, could i just ask- what does the `a` do?

Comment: That is called a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression).  I iterate through each item in `array1` (calling it `a`) and see if that item, `a`, is in `answer`.  `any()` returns True if any one of those is True.

Comment: so if you were to do multiple types of these in one code would you use different letters?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.  If you use the same letter, it just means that `a` won't refer to the last item in the iterable anymore.  It doesn't affect any of the generator expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you -

```
if any(x in answer for x in array1):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("fail")
```

> any(iterable, /)
>       Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.

Answer (score 2):

```
    print ("yes" if any(x in answer for x in array1) else "fail")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [set()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to compare 2 lists.

```
>>> array1 = ["hello","hi","hey"]
>>> answer = ["hi","there"]
>>> set(array1) & set(answer)
{'hi'}
```

So this may works:

```
if len(set(array1) & set(answer))>0:
```

Comment: Little bit more explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
array1=["hello","hi","hey"]
q1=input("say hello-""\n")

answer=q1.split()

def check(keywords, words):
    for kw in keywords:
        if kw in words: return True
    return False

if check(array1, answer):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("fail")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
say hello-
test no keywords
fail

say hello-
hello world
yes

say hello-
no key words
fail
```

Comment: this seems to work but when i typed no keywords in it still said yes `say hello-
no key words
yes`

Comment: How can I reproduce it?